# Django: 'User' object has no attribute 'perfil_de_usuario'

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make a page that, after the user is logued in, shows a list of diferent actions.
The proble is that, when the user is succesfully authenticated, the resulting page is this error:

```
AttributeError at /iniciar_sesion/
'User' object has no attribute 'perfil_de_usuario'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/iniciar_sesion/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'perfil_de_usuario'
Exception Location: /home/jenifer/Documentos/qbit/mysite4/usuarios/models.py in guardar_usuario_perfil, line 25
```

The model is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Perfil_de_Usuario(models.Model):
    idusuario = models.AutoField(db_column='idUsuario', primary_key=True)
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    clave = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    web = models.URLField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Usuario'

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def crear_usuario_perfil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        perfil_de_usuario.objects.create(usuario=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def guardar_usuario_perfil(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.perfil_de_usuario.save()
```

For what the error says, the problem is with `guardar_usuario_perfil`, but I'm not getting how to modify it for this thing to work.

I know there are similar posts and I've tried different solutions like rename         `instance.perfil_de_usuario.save()` part but the result is the same.

If somebody can help me I will apreciate it very much

Comment: It looks like your `Perfil_de_Usuario` has no `OneToOneField` to the `User` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) so that Django can add a reverse relation on the User model

```
class Perfil_de_Usuario(models.Model):
    idusuario = models.OneToOne(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="perfil_de_usuario")
    ....
```

The `related_name="perfil_de_usuario"` is what Django will add to the User model so that you can do what you were trying to do on the signals.

Also, note I didn't use the user model directly in the OneToOneField but used `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead as it is the recommended way.

[Here is the Django documentation on extending the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seemss to work and now I understand what's going on, but now the problem is that it doesn't seem to find the table in the database: 'django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Usuario'. Here it's ok to post this or should I open a new thread?

Comment: Since you have `managed=False` Django will not create the table for you via migrations. It is assumed you already have it or will create it yourself. Django will not manage it for you. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed

Comment: Yes, I've changed that value to true, but the problem persists...also tried to remove the database and the migrations folder and run makemigrations and migrate... which didn't work. Again, thanks for your reply

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what is wrong. Normally makemigrations and migrate should have worked. Did makemigrations create a file with CreateModel?

Comment: I don't see that file. Also, I've tried sqlmigrate and it didn't work; and when I explore the database, the table 'Usuario' isn't there

Comment: That's very strange. I won't be able to help without seeing your project setup and if/what errors occur. Someone else might be able to help you if it's another question.